# A number sequence in disguise

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

**What number should replace the question mark? Explain why.**

---

```
                              10051005
                               51005
                              1001005
                            10010010055
                              10055100
                              10051005
                              1005100
                            10051005100  
                                 ?
                              10051005
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The number that should replace the question mark is:

> 55100100100

Because:

> Each number is composed of some sequence of `100`s and `5`s. If you replace these with their Roman numeral equivalents, `C` and `V`, you get:
>
> ```
>           10051005         CVCV
>            51005           VCV
>           1001005          CCV
>         10010010055        CCCVV
>           10055100         CVVC
>           10051005         CVCV
>           1005100          CVC
>         10051005100        CVCVC
>              ?              ?
>           10051005         CVCV
> ```

About four lines down...

> I noticed that while `C` and `V` strongly suggest `consonant` and `vowel`, one of the only words that fits the pattern `CCCVV` is `THREE`.  So this is a list of the names of digits (*a number sequence*), with each letter replaced with `C` or `V`, and then the `C` or `V` converted from roman numerals to arabic numerals (*in disguise*).
>
> ```
>           10051005         CVCV    zero
>            51005           VCV     one
>           1001005          CCV     two
>         10010010055        CCCVV   three
>           10055100         CVVC    four
>           10051005         CVCV    five
>           1005100          CVC     six
>         10051005100        CVCVC   seven
>         55100100100        VVCCC   eight
>           10051005         CVCV    nine
> ```

Comment: Yup that's correct. Well done!

Comment: It looked like a cipher puzzle at first!